# BeautifulSoup - Cant filter list results by punctuation

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I am trying to exclude question marks and colons from my results in Python however they keep showing up in the final output. The results are filtering by 'None' but not by punctuation.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#Scrape BBC for Headline text
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all(class_='gs-c-promo-heading__title')
#print(headlines)
headlines = list()

for i in tags:
    if i.string is not None:
        if i.string != ":":
            if i.string != "?":
                headlines.append(i.string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the whole string against the chars, but wanna know if the string contains a char - If you really wanna do it that way just use `not in` to do the job:

```
if ':' not in i.string:
    if '?' not in i.string:
```

Problem with your method is, that you will skip results. Think it would be much better to clean the results in the loop and replace such characters:

```
for i in tags:
    print(i.string.replace(':', '').replace(':',''))
```

There is maybe a better way with regex if you wanna clean more characters.

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all(class_='gs-c-promo-heading__title')
#print(headlines)
headlines = list()

for i in tags:
    if i.string is not None:
        if ':' not in i.string:
            if '?' not in i.string:
                headlines.append(i.string)
headlines
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex formatting function to exclude `?` and `:` from the string :

```
def hd_format(text):
   return re.sub(r"\?|\:", "", text)
```

You can add any other character you want to exclude, just separate them with `|` and use `\` to escape special characters

**Complete code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Scrape BBC for Headline text
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all(class_='gs-c-promo-heading__title')
#print(headlines)
headlines = []

def hd_format(text):
    return re.sub(r"\?|\:", "", text)

for i in tags:
    if i.string is not None:
        headlines.append(hd_format(i.string))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still let the punctuation I needed removed through. Maybe this applies to an older version of BeautifulSoup. On line 4, my version did not recognise the "bs" abbriviation. I do appreciate the help however.

Comment: If you only want to remove ? and : my code should work. the"bs" is the way I import it. I will update my code to match your import